# Jquery automatic load function in slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found nice slideshow:

tutorialzine.com/2014/05/jquery-image-slideshow-plugin/

but it works only after clicking activate button. How to modify .js file:

```
(function ($) {
$('#activate').on('click', function () {
    $('img').slideShow({
        timeOut: 2000,
        showNavigation: true,
        pauseOnHover: true,
        swipeNavigation: true
    });
}(jQuery));
```

so that it works automatically. Greets.

Comment: you can use trigger click on set Interval

Answer (score 0):

You can use set Interval function for interval of every 2 seconds the activate button will get clicked, Here is the example

```
setInterval(function() {
         $('#activate').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside the document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function()}{
        $('img').slideShow({
            timeOut: 2000,
            showNavigation: true,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            swipeNavigation: true
        });
    })
```

Comment: Not working :/ I put it in .js file. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Comment: $('#activate').on('click'); try this with your original code